# Search and replace in array of strings

Tags: dataframe, julia

Say I have an array (loaded from a .csv file) `A = ["Aaaa", "BAaaa", "CAaaa"]` and I want to make all the uppercase A's in to lowercase, i.e `A = ["aaaa","Baaaa","Caaaa"]`.

My first guess was to use `@enum` in some way but apparently that only works on floats. I have tried to create a function which takes elements of A as arguments and then uses `if/ifelse` statements to check whether or not there is an uppercase A in there. But I can't figure out how to 'search and replace'.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: What does this have to do with DataFrames?

Comment: Since my data is loaded from a .csv file I thought I had to use DataFrames(?) Apologies for the confusion, Julia is my first programming language and I am self-studying.

Comment: You can use [CSV.jl](https://github.com/JuliaData/CSV.jl)'s `read` method which returns a `DataFrame`. But there is also `readcsv`/`readdlm` in Julia's Base which returns an (heterogeneous) array. Anyways, your question assumes an array and is hence not related to DataFrames. BTW, I would have loved to have Julia as my first programming language.

Comment: Ah, I see. I approved your edit. I am also very excited to be learning Julia, just having a hard time with the syntax but I suppose that will get better with time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have an array of strings (your code was missing quotation marks), like this:

```
julia> A = ["Aaaa", "BAaaa", "CAaaa"]
3-element Array{String,1}:
 "Aaaa"
 "BAaaa"
 "CAaaa"
```

If this is the case this is the way to replace `"A"` with `"a"` in an array of strings:

```
julia> replace.(A, "A", "a")
3-element Array{String,1}:
 "aaaa"
 "Baaaa"
 "Caaaa"
```

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for the help. Just one question: If I have understood correctly, the `.` in `replace.` means that we apply the replace function to each element in A?

Comment: exactly, see https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/functions/#man-vectorized-1